# Easily create instance of Java DTO object from Scala code

Tags: java, scala, gwt

I am converting the server side of my GWT project use Scala instead of Java.  I have a number of RPC servlets that do DB lookups then map results to ArrayList where a class like SomeDTO might be

```
  override def listTrips(): util.ArrayList[TripRoleDTO] = {
    val trd = new TripRoleDTO
    trd.setRoleType(RoleType.TripAdmin)
    trd.setTripName(sessionDataProvider.get().getSessionUser.getEmail)
    val res: util.ArrayList[TripRoleDTO] = new util.ArrayList[TripRoleDTO]()
    res.add(trd)
    res
  }
```

instead of

```
@Override
public ArrayList<TripRoleDTO> listTrips() {
    final SessionData sessionData = sessionDataProvider.get();
    final List<TripRole> tripsForUser = tripAdminProvider.get().listTripRolesForUser(sessionData.getSessionUser().getId());
    return newArrayList(transform(tripsForUser, DTOConverter.convertTripRole));
}
```

Note that the Java implementation actually makes the DB call (something I'm figuring out in Scala still) but it does its DTO transformation via Google Guava's [Iterables.transform](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r8/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#transform%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) method.

Since the DTO objects need to be .java files that the client side of GWT can use what is an elegant way to transform my Scala domain objects to DTOS?

Answer (score 1):

Use the GWT [RequestFactory](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html) for automating the creation of DTOs. The DTO can be defined simply with an interface and a @ProxyFor annotation, see an example in the link provided.

If using RequestFactory by some reason is not an alternative, then consider using [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) to map domain objects to DTOs, this is frequently used with GWT.